# Selenium Python Exception even though Selenium succeeds and clicks

Tags: python, selenium

in short I am getting an exception after the code that gives the exception suceeds.

```
def checkelementid(id1):
    try:
        second_driver.find_element_by_id(id1).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        return False
    return True

if checkelementid("requisitionDescriptionInterface.UP_APPLY_ON_REQ.row1"):
    print("before")
    second_driver.find_element_by_id("requisitionDescriptionInterface.UP_APPLY_ON_REQ.row1").click()
    print("after")
```

I get the following error after the click succeeds and I go to a new url:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="requisitionDescriptionInterface.UP_APPLY_ON_REQ.row1"]
```

So it actually finds the element and clicks and get taken to a new site but it somehow runs the click again on the new site but obviously cant find the element. It prints "before" but does not print "after".

Comment: your code tells the driver to find an element with that id, it finds it, then it clicks on it.  The browser then loads a new page.  The driver will wait for the pageload to complete.  Then you attempt to find an element with the same id and click on it.  At that point the driver throws an element not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put wait before **if** condition.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```